# How to truncate a snowflake table before loading it from AWS Glue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are having some AWS Glue jobs , which are reading the data from Amazon S3 Locations and writing data into snowflake tables.  We want to truncate the tables before each load.  could someone helping me to do this.

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run [truncate](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/truncate-table.html#truncate-table) query

```
truncate table if exists table_name;
```

If what you are asking is how to create an ETL that incorporate the AWS Glue job with running query on Snowflake that is depended on the ETL tool that you use and what it can do. That however is a question for the ETL tool that you are using.
i can suggest using [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) which can schedule Glue jobs and run Snowflake queries.

Comment: Hi AWS Glue is the ETL tool that we are doing and inside that we are using python as language.  From there we are not able to fire snowflake sql statements.

Comment: Hi - Python is quite capable of running Snowflake SQL commands e.g. conn.cursor().execute("truncate table if exists table_name")

Answer (score 0):

I am using an AWS Glue as an ETL tool.  I dont to know how to fire an Snowflake DDL Statement from AWS Glue jobs.

Thanks,
Ram.